# Call GET with parameters webservice via Ajax

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net, web-services

I'm trying to call a GET webservice via ajax, the service is found but I can't manage to pass parameters, all combinations of quotes and `JSON.stringify` I googled and tryed failed, these are my attemps (in commented lines you see the `data` parameter formats I tryed:

`$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "webservice/srv_documento.asmx/FijarOrientacionEncabezado",
        //data: JSON.stringify({ IdElementoDoc: parseInt(id_elto), OrientacionVertical: Boolean(texto_vertical) }),
        //data: { IdElementoDoc: parseInt(id_elto), OrientacionVertical: 0 },
        data: JSON.stringify('{ "IdElementoDoc": "1", "OrientacionVertical": "0" }'),
        //data: JSON.stringify({ IdElementoDoc: '"' + id_elto + '"', OrientacionVertical: '"' + texto_vertical + '"' }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            console.log("Ok " + dump(msg));
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log("Error " + dump(msg));
        }
    });`

I get message *missing parameter IdElementoDoc*:

> {"Message":"Llamada al servicio web no válida. Falta un valor para el parámetro: \u0027IdElementoDoc\u0027.","StackTrace":"   en System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethod(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.WebServiceMethodData.CallMethodFromRawParams(Object target, IDictionary`2 parameters)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.InvokeMethod(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData, IDictionary`2 rawParams)\r\n   en System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"}"

This is my service definition (VB):

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)> _
Public Function FijarOrientacionEncabezado(IdElementoDoc As Integer, OrientacionVertical As Integer) As String
    Try
        Dim log As New Logger

        log.log(String.Format("FijarOrientacionEncabezado {0}", IdElementoDoc))


        Return New JSONResponse(True, "ok").serialize()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return New JSONResponse(False, ex.Message).serialize()
    End Try

End Function
```

Comment: You can also use JSONLint to check your JSON to make sure it is valid. [HERE](http://jsonlint.com/)

Comment: try data: JSON.stringify({  IdElementoDoc : 1, OrientacionVertical : 0 })

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak didn't work, I had already tryed a similar one with `data: { IdElementoDoc: parseInt(id_elto), OrientacionVertical: 0 }`

Comment: @Trucktech thanks for the link, JSONLint validates my JSON but doesn't work in webservice call

Comment: `http://myhost/webservice/srv_documento.asmx/FijarOrientacionEncabezado?IdElementoDoc=1&OrientacionVertical=0` what gives you?

Comment: That's what I finally did. Actually, a json data should have worked but I went for the simple solution :-), thanks